# Particular Diophantine equation

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

There are four natural numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ such that $a<b<c<d$. They satisfy the following equation:

$a^2$+$b^2$+$c^2$+$d^2$= $abcd$

What is the smallest possible value of $d$? This is a math puzzle, so please solve it without computers.

Comment: The answer seems to be $262$, but I really don't see how this can be solved with `no-computers`. Also it doesn't look like a suitable question on this site.

Comment: Ah... After a minute's thought, it seems that I got some idea on how to do it without computers. Still not a suitable question for this site, though.

Comment: A hint: if $(a,b,c,d)$ is a solution, then $(a,b,c,abc-d)$ also.

Comment: @WhatsUp Why do you think this isn't a suitable question for this site? It seems like a fine and valid mathematical puzzle to me.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I think it would be much more suitable for the mathematics site. That is, if I am to choose from the two sites (math & puzzle), I would definitely put this question on the math site (although there is a nice idea here, but that is also common in e.g. contest math problems and hence not a characterisation of being a puzzle).

Comment: @WhatsUp Other sites' scope should never be a consideration when deciding whether or not a question is suitable for *this* site; many SE sites have scope overlaps, including Maths and Puzzling. Not sure if you're familiar with [Puzzling's policy on maths problems](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784/5373), but being common in contest maths problems doesn't make something not a puzzle either; quite the contrary, in my opinon, contest maths questions are quite likely to have the "aha" requisite to be on-topic here.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Indeed, I have read that meta post and the most voted answer ends with "*there's lots of grey area in between.*" I understand this as depending on personal taste, and this one doesn't look like a puzzle to me... Nevertheless I didn't vote for close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First, let $2^n$ be the greatest power of $2$ shared among $a,b,c,d$ and write $a=2^n a'$ etc. Then $a'^2+b'^2+c'^2+d'^2 = 4^n a'b'c'd'$. As at least one of the $a',b',c',d'$ is odd, the l.h.s. cannot be a multiple of $8$ and $n$ must be $1$ and $a',b',c',d'$ all odd.

> If we solve for $d'$ we get the Pythagorean quintuple $a'^2 + b'^2 + c'^2 + (d'-2a'b'c')^2 = 4a'^2b'^2c'^2$. In particular, $a'^2 + b'^2 + c'^2$ is of the form $(2a'b'c')^2 - (2a'b'c'-k)^2 = 4ka'b'c'-k^2$.

> Fortunately, a small solution exists in $k=a'=1,b'=3,c'=11$ and this yields $a=2,b=6,c=22,d=262$.

> Note that formally, $k$ and $d'$ satisfy the same equation except for the constraint $d'>a',b',c'$, so our treatment so far may serve as a derivation of @WhatsUp's transform $(a,b,c,d) \mapsto (a,b,c,abc-d)$ which takes solutions (ignoring the $a<b<c<d$ constraint) to solutions.

> So another way of looking at this is: Partially ignore that $a,b,c,d$ must be distinct. Guess solution $a',b',c',d' = 1,1,3,11$ or $a,b,c,d = 2,2,6,22$ and apply WhatsUp's transformation to make the numbers distinct.

> We can take this two steps further: Start from $a,b,c,d = 2,2,2,2$ and apply WhatsUp transform three times: $(2,2,2,2)\rightarrow(2,2,2,6)\rightarrow(2,2,6,22)\rightarrow(2,6,22,262)$